# postgres.yml file missing when using PostgreSQL with Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I seem to have a problem when using PostgreSQL as persistent solution for Yesod.

I followed the steps in the 'Yesod in five minutes' guide.

I used the scaffolder to create a a project. When choosing option t, all went well and I could see the application at: `http://localhost:3000`.

However, when I choose PostgreSQL as database, I got the following error after typing the 'yesod devel' command

```
Registering FirstYesod-0.0.0...
Starting development server...
Starting devel application
devel.hs: InvalidYaml (Just "YamlException \"Yaml file not found: config/postgres.yml\"")
Devel application launched, listening on port 3000
Exit code: ExitFailure 11
```

Is this Yaml file something that should have been added by me, or should the installation process have provided it? 
If so, does anyone have any idea why it wasn't created?

I use PostgreSQL 8.4.9. It works fine with psql and with  PGAdmin III

Answer (score 2):

If you look you'll see the generated `yml` and the opened file have different names:

```
devel.hs: InvalidYaml (Just "YamlException \"Yaml file not found: config/postgres.yml\"")
```

and:

```
$ ls config
favicon.ico  models  postgresql.yml  routes  settings.yml
```

So just copy (or move) the file:

```
$ cp config/postgresql.yml config/postgres.yml
```

Now you get a new error that is postgresql specific:

```
devel.hs: SqlError {seState = "", seNativeError = 1, seErrorMsg = "connectPostgreSQL: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user \"B\"\nFATAL:  password authentication failed for user \"B\"\n"}
```

I'm not a DB person, but if *you* know the answer to this one (in terms of what commands to type after running `psql`) then I'm all ears ;-).

Comment: It means that you need to create the database with the specified username/password. Also, I've opened a Github issue for this bug: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/167

Comment: What I did to get everything working: I created a project in yesod called rj. Then, in postres I created a user rj (CREATE USER rj;), and a database called rj (CREATE DATABASE rj WITH OWNER rj). Note that the lowercase is important, because I couldn't get Postgres to create a database name containing uppercase characters. It would be nice to know where in the Heskell source the connection is made, because I would have liked to get uppercase characters in the project name. Anyway, thanks for the help already.